# Any suggestion to set complex counter twice in this situation?

Tags: counters, setcounter

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% \usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{amsfonts}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, left=1.7cm, top=1.2cm, bottom=1.75cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

  
% \normalsize logo \hfill \fbox{reçu de versement} \hfill  \No : 


\includepdf{receipt}


\end{document}
```

[image: receipt]

1. I want a template that repeat where I increment 3 counters dynamically as describe below
2. The 2 green arrows will always go through 001 to 050 and after that the second part will increment by 2 in the red rectangle and circle.

Comment: Do you want to typeset the receipts one by one (with two going on one page), or do you want to typeset the receipts as pairs? In the first case you have two counters (red and green, with the red one being incremented twice per page), in the second case you have three counters (green, red rectangle, red circle, each incremented only once per page).

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`  utf8x will just generate a warning that it shouldn't be used, and `[utf8]` would do nothing as UTF-8 is the default encoding

Comment: @gernot Yes, I want to typeset the two receipts in the same page. Then, the green must increment by 1 starting 001 until 050 at that time the red remain unchanged. But the next iteration the red rectangle will increment by 2 (always be odd ) and the red circle will increment by 2 ( always even number ).

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you, let me correct it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses a single counter `receipt`. After printing a receipt, increment the counter with `\stepcounter{receipt}`. Within a receipt, you can print the value of the counter in your special format with the command `\TheReceipt`. The numbering follows your scheme: The first number is the same for two successive receipts and goes from 1 to 50. The second number flips between odd and even, but otherwise remains the same for 50 pages, and increases by 2 then.

You need the following definitions in your preamble.

```
\newcounter{receipt}
\newcount\green
\newcount\red
\newcount\tmpa
\newcount\tmpb
\newcommand\TheReceipt{% compute and typeset the numbers
  % compute \green and \red from counter receipt
  \red=\value{receipt}%
  \divide\red by 100
  \tmpa=\red
  \multiply\tmpa by 100
  \green=\value{receipt}%
  \advance\green by -\tmpa
  \tmpa=\green
  \divide\green by 2
  \tmpb=\green
  \multiply\tmpb by 2
  \advance\tmpa by -\tmpb
  \multiply\red by 2
  \advance\red by \tmpa
  \advance\green by 1
  \advance\red by 1
  % typeset the numbers \green and \red with leading zeros
  \ifnum\the\green<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\the\green<10 0\fi
  \the\green
  /%
  \ifnum\the\red<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum\the\red<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\the\red<10 0\fi
  \the\red
}
```

To illustrate the usage, here is a sample code that prints dummy receipts, two per page, for 123 pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, left=1.7cm, top=1.2cm, bottom=1.75cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{receipt}
\newcount\green
\newcount\red
\newcount\tmpa
\newcount\tmpb
\newcommand\TheReceipt{% compute and typeset the numbers
  % compute \green and \red from counter receipt
  \red=\value{receipt}%
  \divide\red by 100
  \tmpa=\red
  \multiply\tmpa by 100
  \green=\value{receipt}%
  \advance\green by -\tmpa
  \tmpa=\green
  \divide\green by 2
  \tmpb=\green
  \multiply\tmpb by 2
  \advance\tmpa by -\tmpb
  \multiply\red by 2
  \advance\red by \tmpa
  \advance\green by 1
  \advance\red by 1
  % typeset the numbers \green and \red with leading zeros
  \ifnum\the\green<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\the\green<10 0\fi
  \the\green
  /%
  \ifnum\the\red<1000 0\fi
  \ifnum\the\red<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\the\red<10 0\fi
  \the\red
}
\newcommand\Receipt{% dummy receipt to demonstrate the use of \TheReceipt
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \fbox{\bfseries REÇU MANUEL DE VERSEMENT}
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
        N$^\circ$ \TheReceipt\\
        Date: 99/99/9999
      \end{tabular}%
    }

    Begin of form\\[0.4\textheight]
    End of form
  \end{minipage}%
  \stepcounter{receipt}%
}

\newcommand\TwoReceipts{% two receipts with a separator
  \clearpage
  \Receipt
  \vspace{5pt}\par
  \dotfill
  \vspace{5pt}\par
  \Receipt
}

\usepackage{ifthen}% for \whiledo below
\newcounter{pages}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
% generate 123 pages, each with two receipts on it
\whiledo{\value{pages}<123}{
  \TwoReceipts
  \stepcounter{pages}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me and the community @gernot .